# Cannot write to a .txt file using write() function in C

Tags: c, system-calls

I wrote the following code in order to write some random characters to a text file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int input_f = open("./input.txt", O_CREAT | O_APPEND |  O_RDWR ,0666);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        int r = rand()%252;
        printf("%d size of r: %d\n",i,sizeof(r));
        write(input_f,r,sizeof(r));
        printf("%d we just wrote %d which is %c\n",i,r,r);
    }

    close(input_f);
}
```

I looked for some solutions to do this

Maybe someone here knows how can I fix this?

Comment: Why not random and what do you mean "not formatted"?

Comment: What error do you get?  I'm guessing none, because your code doesn't print any error messages.  Try checking the return value of `open` and `write` and writing an error message if they fail.  (`man perror` and `man strerror`)

Comment: Seeing the error he got when he called `write` would give it away as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
write(input_f,r,sizeof(r));
```

should be

```
write(input_f, &r, sizeof(r));
```

The second parameter is the address of the buffer you want to send according to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/write).

Also you should check the return value of the function to be equal to `sizeof r`.

Answer (score 1):

`write(input_f,r,sizeof(r));` should be `write(input_f,&r,sizeof(r));` because write takes a pointer to the data to be written, not the data directly.

Other then that you should be checking the result of the open call, and write calls they can fail.

Comment: Beaten to it by mch.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `write` wrong.

If you'd included `unistd.h`,  you would have gotten a prototype and the compiler would have corrected you.

```
write(input_f,&r,sizeof(r)); //the 2nd arg is a void const*
```

Also, `size_t` arguments to `printf` require `"%zu"`, and you should be checking for errors.

Comment: Thanks you for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

Others have already said why it doesn't work

I just want to add that you should also write :

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

Or else you'll get warnings during compilation.

Comment: Thanks you for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

The write() function do not take an int as second parameter but a pointer (void *) on a buffer, and its length. It means you will have to convert your int into a string in a buffer first (with sprintf() for instance) and then output the buffer to the file (with write())